# Cannot save data into mysql database using ADODB in VB2010

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, adodb

I am new to VB.net and I am using VS 2010, I want to save some data into my MySQL database table (Inbox) with the following Fields(Message=mediumtext, Phone=varchar 15) but it says

> object reference not set to an instance of an object

```
    Public Sub OpenRecord(ByVal sql As String)
      Connection() //this to call my database connection
      Try
        If rs.State = 1 Then rs.Close()
          rs.Open(sql, con, 1, 2)
      Catch ex As Exception
          MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Information)
      End Try
    End Sub
```

I then call the above SUB from a Button_Click event

```
    OpenRecord("Select * From Inbox")
    With rs
        .AddNew() //this is where i got the error and if i remove this line the next two lines will have the same error.
        .Fields("Message").Value = Me.txtmsg.Text
        .Fields("Phone").Value = Me.txtnum.Text
        .Update()
    End With
```

Comment: You should use MySQL connector for .NET http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/ you will get  fully-managed ADO.NET driver instead relying on ADODB.

Comment: so here is my connection string...please take a look sir
//
con.ConnectionString = "Driver=MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver;Server=localhost;Database=***;User=***;Password=***;Option=3"

Comment: As suggested, you should ditch that method of data access altogether and use ADO.NET.  If you're going to use a .NET language then why use a data access technology developed well before .NET and superseded when .NET was created?  You gain nothing and lose much.  That said, if you get a `NullReferenceException` then a reference on that line is `null`.  It's VERY easy to determine which.  Which line is the exception thrown on?  Look at each reference on that line when it's running and see which is `null`.

Comment: both comments are helpful, I use MySql.Data.MySqlClient now to communicate with MySQL database , salute to both.